# How to structure a categorized voting database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, database-design, voting

I have a question about how to structure a DB.  I have a reddit'esque voting system.  Items can get votes.  But each item belongs to a topic and each topic a category.  While only items can get votes I'd like to be able to access the # of votes within a topic and within a category as well.  Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

I see 4 main ways of doing this:

1. De-normalize the votes and store the votes inside an attribute in the item table, the topic table, and the category table.  I would then need to update all 3 whenever a vote / downvote occurs.
2. Create a separate 'vote' model.  Votes belong to items, items to topics, and topics to categories.  Then I can just query number of votes through the chain whenever I need to access anything.
3. Just have items and votes. Items would have a category and topic attribute.. then I'd query for items within a topic and count the votes on them..
4. Learn to use a NoSQL db system.

Extra info:  I'm using Rails and I only really know MYSQL at the moment.  Is this a time I should learn something like Mongo?  Can this only really be accomplished with Hadoop?  Can I accomplish this in MySQL.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't know enough about your tools to answer your question, but from a database perspective option number 2 is the only sensible solution.  This type of thing is exactly what RDBMS is built for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Create a separate 'vote' model. Votes belong to items, items to
>   topics, and topics to categories. Then I can just query number of
>   votes through the chain whenever I need to access anything.

That's the most flexible way to do what you're talking about.

> Learn to use a NoSQL db system.

Not for your current project.

> Is this a time I should learn something like Mongo?

No.

> Can this only really be accomplished with Hadoop?

No. Any SQL database can do this. Whether any SQL database can manage whatever you're planning is a different question. Different platforms scale differently.

> Can I accomplish this in MySQL.

Yes, easily.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should got for option 2.

You need to create a vote model anyway, since you'll probably want to limit users to one vote on each item.

**If** you have performance issues later on, you can always cache the number of votes in an item, topic or category.

How you update those numbers should be carefully considered. A trigger on votes that auto-updates all the numbers above might cause too many write operations. Another way may be to run a statistics stored procedure periodically.

Anyway, the real point is - **don't optimize until you know there's a problem**.